# Overplot SunPy HEK polygon mask on custom numpy array instead of Sunpy Map

Tags: python, numpy, matplotlib, matplotlib-basemap, astropy

I'm working on sunspot detection and I'm trying to build ground truth masks using sunpy.net.hek client to download solar events from the knowledge base. 
I followed this [tutorial](http://docs.sunpy.org/en/v0.9.0/generated/gallery/overplot_hek_polygon.html).
My problem is that I'm not able to get the polygon pixel coordinates after the rotation. That is:

```
ch_boundary = SkyCoord( [(float(v[0]), float(v[1])) * u.arcsec for v in p3], 
                         obstime=ch_date, 
                         frame=frames.Helioprojective)

rotated_ch_boundary = solar_rotate_coordinate(ch_boundary, aia_map.date)
```

Where `p3` holds the original coordinates of the event (they have to be rotated because your picture could not have the same timing as the event on hek). `rotated_ch_boundary` is an Astropy SkyCoord but cannot figure out how to get the coordinates in pixel relative to the image from that.
Then in the tutorial it just plots the coordinates using Sunpy Map and matplotlib:

```
aia_map.plot(axes=ax)
ax.plot_coord(rotated_ch_boundary, color='c')
```

I cannot do that because I want to print the polygon (filled) on a numpy array and save it.
I also tried to build a custom Sunpy map and use the same function to plot:

```
from sunpy.net.helioviewer import HelioviewerClient

hv = HelioviewerClient()
filepath = hv.download_jp2('2017/07/10 10:00:00', observatory='SDO', 
               instrument='HMI', detector='HMI', measurement='continuum')
hmi = sunpy.map.Map(filepath)

# QUERY AND ROTATION CODE HERE...

hmi.plot(axes=ax)
ax.plot_coord(rotated_ch_boundary, color='c')
```

but it doesn't even show the polygon on the plot, I don't know if it's for the different resolution or whatever.

Do you have any idea on how I can plot the polygon on a custom image and save it in order to use it later?

My purpose is to create a black image with a white polygon highlighted. The polygon should be in the exact same position as the sunspot in the corresponding image, let's say an SDO HMI intensitygram of the same day I downloaded from helioviewer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
aia_map.world_to_pixel(rotated_ch_boundary)
```

or

```
rotated_ch_boundary.to_pixel(aia_map.wcs)
```

Thanks to fraserwatson for [this post](https://github.com/sunpy/sunpy/issues/2685)